# Element is not render in browser - React

Tags: html, reactjs

Why my element is not rendered in browser? I just want to see the h1 from react.doc in browser.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, everyone!</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
```